# "Next t" value in sub not carrying to function

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and trying to write a simple macro. I have pasted my code below. Basically, I have 11 random numbers in cells B5 through B15. If this number is  less than 0.65 I would like it to print TRUE in the column next to it. If it is greater than 0.65 I would like it to print FALSE in the column next to it. I think I basically have the code down, however a "Next t" in the Sub PrintandRead, t will have a value 5 through 15 (which is correct) however then it goes up to the markov function where t then returns to t=0. Why is it not carrying the "Next t" value up into the function?

```
Option Explicit

Function markov(pwd As Double, pww As Double) As Boolean
    Static wetYesterday As Boolean
    pwd = 0.4
    pww = 0.65
    Dim c As Double
    Dim t As Double
    If wetYesterday Then c = t - pww Else c = t - pwd
    If c <= 0 Then
        wetYesterday = True: markov = True
    Else
    wetYesterday = False: markov = False
    End If
End Function


Sub ReadAndPrint()
    Dim t As Double
    Dim p As Double
    Dim z(11) As Double
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    p = 2
    For t = 5 To 15
        z(t - 4) = Cells(t, p)
    Next t
    p = p + 1
    For t = 5 To 15
    Cells(t, p) = markov(0.4, 0.65)
    'z(t - 4)
    Next t

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have a variable called `t` in your `markov` function, this is a different variable to the one in the main `ReadAndPrint` method. This is called scope - as you declare each variable within each method, it is scoped to that method. You can use the same name again elsewhere, but its a completely different variable (and could have a different type etc).

The best thing you could do would be to pass `t` into the `markov` method as a parameter by changing the declaration:

```
Function markov(pwd As Double, pww As Double,t as Double) As Boolean
```

and calling it with

```
Cells(t, p) = markov(0.4, 0.65, z(t - 4))
```

You should also delete the `Dim t As Double` from the `markov` function.

Comment: It uses the value '5' for t, which t should be the value in the 5th row, not 5. How can I fix this?

Comment: You read the value out of the cell already, and put it into `z(t - 4)`, so pass that in to the function instead of just `t`.

Comment: Like this? It doesnt seem to be working. Sorry, I am very lost and have been working on this for a very long time.  Function markov(pwd As Double, pww As Double, z(t-4) As Double) As Boolean
    Static wetYesterday As Boolean
    pwd = 0.4
    pww = 0.65
    Dim c As Double
    If wetYesterday Then c = z(t - 4) - pww Else c = t - pwd
    If c <= 0 Then
        wetYesterday = True: markov = True
    Else
    wetYesterday = False: markov = False
    End If
End Function

Comment: No, in the call - that's where you have `z(t-4)` available (in scope!) See my edited line.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- The super easiet would be:

In the C column do this: `=IF(B5 > 0.65, "TRUE", "FALSE")`

- Here is a simpler version of a VBA to do the same.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub checkGreatness()
Dim inputRng As Range
Dim arrInput As Variant
Dim i As Integer

    '--get user input
    Set inputRng = Application.InputBox("Please enter Column Range", "Enter the Range", , , , , , 8)
    If inputRng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '--populate array with that range
    arrInput = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(inputRng.Value)

    For i = LBound(arrInput) To UBound(arrInput)
        If IsEmpty(arrInput(i)) Then
            arrInput(i) = "NoValue"
        ElseIf Round(arrInput(i), 2) < 0.65 Then
            arrInput(i) = "True"
        Else
            arrInput(i) = "False"
        End If
    Next i

    '--output to next column
    inputRng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(arrInput), 1) = Application.Transpose(arrInput)

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @user1977802 if you are interested you may take a look at this. Turn this into a function as well :)